# retrofit 2: POST JSON body and XML response

Tags: post, gson, retrofit, retrofit2, simple-framework

I would like to know if it is posible send a request with a JSON body and get the XML response with retrofit 2.

If I add two .addFactoryConverter() methods retrofit just use the first one for both the request and the response.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please move your edit to an answer and accept it. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Thank you, I thought that I cannot do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code I could solve the problem. https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/JsonAndXmlConverters.java

Comment: how did you annotated requests (services) in interface that you want to send json and accept xml?

Comment: I dont remember right now how do I solved it but I think that I have to modify the code above and use as a factory converter in the retrofit client.